# median of merged sorted array returning wrong value

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, dynamic, time-complexity

The goal is to merge two sorted arrays, and return a median(double).

I am creating a larger array of size *nums1+nums2*
and while iterating through, adding the value of the smaller element into the large array.
keeping pointers for each given one.

**I cannot tell if my array is being populated, and it is returning 0 for most cases, and "divide by 0" error  for others;**

```
class Solution {
    public double findMedianSortedArrays(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {
        int len = nums1.length+nums2.length;
        int[] nums = new int[len];
        int pone=0;
        int ptwo=0;
        double ans;
        
        for(int i=0;i>nums.length;i++){
            if(pone==nums1.length) nums[i] = nums2[ptwo++];
            else if(ptwo==nums2.length) nums[i] = nums1[pone++];
            if(nums1[pone]<nums2[ptwo] && pone<nums1.length){
                nums[i]=nums1[pone];
                pone++;
            }else if(nums1[pone]>nums2[ptwo] && ptwo<nums2.length){
                nums[i] = nums2[ptwo];
                ptwo++;
            }
            System.out.print(nums[i]);
        }
        if(len%2==0) ans = nums[len/2] / nums[(len/2)-1];
        else ans = nums[len/2];
        
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `>` in `for(int i=0;i>nums.length;i++)` seems like a typo, since `i` with value 0 cannot be greater than `nums.length`. So the loop body will never run.

Comment: In all likelihood, you are expected to find that median much faster than in proportion to  the sum of sizes, using constant space in addition to the input.

Comment: (Do you ever need/read an element of `nums` beyond index `len/2`? Or before `len/2 - 1`, at that.)

Comment: @greybeard I realize that this solution is not the efficiency required. I will try and implement a binary algorithm next.